# How can I Access Application from Remote system

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, dedicated-server

Recently we bought dedicated server with windows server 2012 standard,we deployed Java Application using Apache Tomcat. using this link `***.**.*.**:8080/Application` I open that Application through browser in dedicated server,it's working fine.

That same link we triggered from another systems,it's not showing anything.

I don't know,Why it was not working in another systems,for this I tried in the following ways.

For my conformation,I ping my server from my localsystem in the following way,It's working fine.

```
 ping ***.**.*.**
```

Also I turned of firewall from control panel,still it's not working.

For this, Am I need to open ports in my dedicated server.

How can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to ping your server from other systems? Have you checked the firewall settings?

Comment: @braindead I tried `ping`,it's working.I don't about firewall settings.Where will I find in remote server

Comment: Simply turn the firewall off from control panel. Then try to load your app in a browser. The recommended setting is to have the firewall on and punch holes in which ever port you want exposed. For HTTP requests I suppose you need 80 open.

Comment: @braindead I open controlPanel-->security-->Windows firewall-->AllowedApps. I selected `Public` option beside of `Branch Cache-content Retrieval(use Http)`.still it's not working. Is it right what I did.

Comment: I tried in another way. I open controlPanel-->security-->Windows firewall-->customize setting.I turn off the fire wall under public network.still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to open up ports in the firewall protecting the server, for external connections.
Or it could be that you're accessing the server using its loopback address locally, which obviously won't work from an external source (you need to use a public IP address).
It would help if you supplied more information though: Address of the computer, address you used to access the service, location of your other systems etc.

Comment: I don't know about firewall settings, where will I find.what do you mean loopback address.we are using dedicated server with static IP Address.I tried with `ping` it's working fine.

Comment: I turn off the public fire wall settings,still it's not working.How can fix this.

Comment: Contact the provider of the dedicated server. It is very hard to tell you where the problem lies, but most likely they can help you.
Sorry for not being more helpful, but they are in a much better position to tell you where the problem is. We have too little information

Comment: We contacted dedicated guys.They resolved the problem.Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear! No problem :)